# Question about An Abstract Approach to the Poisson Integral in Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image]

[image]

I'm reading Rudin RCA chap 5 about Poisson Integral.
I don't understand why if $f=u_{n}=w^n$ satisfies the equation, then $f=u_{n}(e^{ix})=e^{inx}$also satisfies. The right side of the equation $f(e^{it})={e^{in{e^{it}}}}$, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures of text and equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: it is not a written rule but a suggested policy to  post a pictures of text. The title if good enough for a search of similar questions.

Comment: @OliverDias:  Do you understand *WHY* unsearchable is discouraged?  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31982/210401. And this title is certainly *not* good enough to find "similar" questions.

Comment: Linear combinations of the functions $w^{n}$ are dense in $C(T)$. You are mis-interpreting the notations . You cannot take $f=e^{inx}$ with $x \in T$.